# Google Maps API, Setting a name of marker when getting directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a program that allows the user to select multiple items for a trip. Part of the program maps the items in google maps. I am using the lat/long coordinates to generate the waypoints and then the API takes it from there. The final map shows the route and markers. I would like to give each marker a custom name instead of the default street address currently being displayed. Is this possible?

```
    //Display the route on the map
    $.post("processors/getMapWayPoints.php",{
        tripID: tripID
    }, function(e){
        console.log("Return is " + e);
        latlong = JSON.parse(e);

            //iterate through each locations lat/long and add it to the mappoints array for the route plotting
            for(var i = 0; i < latlong.length; i+=3){
                var name = latlong[i];
                var lat = latlong[i+1];
                var lng = latlong[i+2];
                //create google lat/long point object
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                //add the location to the array for the route
                mappoints.push({location:pt, stopover:true});
                //not being used yet
                pointNames.push(name);
            }

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom:11,
                center: home
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            var request = {
                origin:home,
                destination:home,
                waypoints: mappoints,
                //optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Where do you want to "give each marker a custom name"? It the directions panel?  On the map? What do you mean by "a custom name"?

Comment: Each marker that is displayed by this on the map will display the address in a popup/mini-modal when clicked on. Instead of the address, I would like to display the name. Most of these markers are for restaurants or public places.

Comment: You want to make a custom [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) for each marker?

Comment: I want the generated markers from the directions renderer to have a name instead of the address. That simple.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs_busRoute.html)? Or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html)?

Comment: Ah yes! The second one is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: So how do I do that?

Comment: View source doesn't work?